# Prevent switching of Keyboard Layout on Windows

Tags: keyboard, windows-11, keyboard-layout

Its annoying me to no end.

My Keyboard is a French (Canada) keyboard. I have it set as that, usually.

But multiple times per day, Windows seems to decide my keyboard should be English (US), or French (France) making specials characters suddenly not the same place. I need to go into the keyboards settings and put back French (Canada).

I did go down the settings and there was a shortcut I'm 99% sure that I do not hit regularly, and disabled it, with no luck.

Is there a way to simply just say to Windows 'This is my fu**** keyboard, don't change it except if I go into the deep keyboard layout settings'?

Its annoying as all hell.

Comment: What are you doing when it switches layouts? What are you language settings in *Settings > Time & Language > Language* (a screenshot would be best)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Windows anymore, but I remember I had that exact same problem some time ago. The problem was that Windows had assigned CTRL+Shift to change layouts. I don't exactly remember the path in Control Panel to change that, maybe try looking into Accessibility Options.

Another option is to just remove the US layout from your keyboards list, and keep just one layout there. That way, Windows can't switch it :)

Something that might also help understand this behavior, is add a keyboard toolbar to the taskbar, so you can always visualize what layout is currently on use. You can also change the layout faster through it.

Comment: Yeah I tried to remove every configuration except the one I want; but I have a french keyboard (I speak french usually, so I do need é and ç and all that) but I prefer my windows in english. But it seems you can't remove the english keyboard if your windows is in english. Annoying AF. And I am a webdev, so I guess thats why I always hit it unwillingly; I have a good few amount of shortcuts that start with Ctrl+Shift